What to fill in the document number while applying for Schengen visa "C"?
One of my Nepalese friends works in India and has never required a residence permit from Nepal. Nepalese citizens may live and work freely in India under the 1950 Indo-Nepal Treaty of Peace and Friendship. However, filling out this (document number) is required while applying for Schengen visa "C". What should we fill in this (see image)? Thank you!


You can fill it out with your ID card number (your passport or Nepalese ID number). You can submit an explanation in a cover letter and attach it to your application.

@PustamRaut Passport number and the date it expires. If the form contains a 'remarks' field, then add a remark that Nepalese citizens do not require a residence permit for India. (The consulate officials will probably know this allready). This a case of a badly designed form that doesn't take into account that specific nationalities do not require a residence permit for India.

@MarkJohnson Thank you for clarifications.
